# Bind Docker container to specific ipv6 address

Tags: docker, ipv6

Currently I have my Docker container listening on a specific external ip address using:

`docker run -p 44.44.44.44:80:80`

where `44.44.44.44` is an example external ip. Is it possible to achieve the same result using an ipv6 address? Just replacing the v4 isn't working. I also tried different methods using the --ip6 option with no succes.

Comment: What is the example command that you ran?

Comment: `docker run -p "x:x:x:x::1":80:80 -it ubuntu` gives the error too many colons in address. The same error without the quotation marks. Using `docker run -p 80:80 --ip6 x:x:x:x::1 -it ubuntu` gives "Error response from daemon: user specified IP address is supported on user defined networks only.". But I believe that functionality is used for creating docker containers on local ip's instead of external.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IPv6 addresses, enclose them in square brackets, e.g.:

```
docker run -d -p [::1]:80:80 nginx
```